# Execute actions in main() after closing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, execution, windowlistener

I am sorry, for I believe that this question has been asked already, but none of the answers have actually helped me out.
I have a class with gui, it contains a JFrame with several textfields and buttons. Here's the main() I'm trying to get working:

```
Gui interface1 = new Gui();
interface1.setSize(200,200);
interface1.setVisible(true);
//hold main execution
//wait for the pressed button in gui
//close the jframe
//proceed with main()
call_some_functions();
```

I have tried setting default close operation to HIDE_ON_CLOSE but that doesn't seem to be what I want. I'm using a framework and I need main() to be alive for quite a long time.
Basically, I need jframe to hold the main() for the time of user input and updating parameters, then close itself without terminating the process and continue with main() as if nothing has happened. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Exiting Jframe calls System.exit(0) which is not what I want. The question is, how can I call_some_fuction() after closing the JFrame, since now call_some_function() executes right after JFrame pops out.

Comment: move mouse to the windowListener tag, click to the FAQ, your question is correct, event not clear described

Comment: I can't stack everything I have in main() into some windowClosed(e) function, I need main to continue executing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uses a `JDialog` instead of `JFrame` and make the `JDialog` modal, using `JDialog#setModal` to `true`

See [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information

Comment: I can't belive it was that simple. interface1.setModal(true) is the answer. Thank you.

Comment: +1 nice and simple, probably better off using JDialog anyway as it doesnt seem to be a full blown UI

Comment: How you came to know what user wants?Cause language ain't english.

Comment: I read his code and deduced the meaning - *//hold main execution* - the only way to do that in Swing is to use a JDialog ;)

Comment: @david depending on the requirements, a JOptionPane may be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

EG:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class TestFrame {
public static void main(String aa[])
{JFrame frame =new JFrame();
 JTextField field=new JTextField("hello buddy..nuthin happnd");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.add(field);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

**UPDATE AS PER YOUR NEEDS:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class TestFrame {
public static void main(String aa[])
{
JFrame frame =new JFrame();
JTextField field=new JTextField("hello buddy..nuthin happnd");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(field);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);


 frame. addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentHidden(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            formComponentHidden(evt);
        }
    });
 }

 private static void formComponentHidden(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
   somefunction();
  }
 public static void somefunction()
 {
  System.out.println("hii!! i am hidden!!");

  }
 }
```

Comment: OP said "I have tried setting default close operation to HIDE_ON_CLOSE but that doesn't seem to be what I want."

Comment: In that case, call_some_functions() executes before closing JFrame. I need JFrame closed, and THEN proceed with main.

Comment: @user1974708 well,this is not very well understood.Do you want to go to main, as soon as the window is closed?Thats what you want?